# (Java) How to acquire number of elements within a item in a list?

Tags: java, list, object, sizing

I have found plenty of questions and answers on here about how to access the number of elements within a list, but I haven't seen a question asked about how to access the number of elements within a certain item on a list.

I have a list of Point arrays that contain the ordered pairs of a polygon. (one list element for each polygon)(there will only ever be two polygons) I need to create new lists that are dynamically sized based on the number of elements WITHIN a certain index in this list. (ex. if the first polygon has eight points, I need to create a new List of size eight and put those eight points in it. Same for the second based on its number.) I know the List Class contains a `size()` function, but trying :

```
private List<Poly.Point[]> mergePolyList;
mergePolyList = LayoutMerger.mergePolyList; 
//LayoutMerger is a separate Java file where I made the arrays
Poly.Point [] pArrayBox1 = new Poly.Point[mergePolyList.get(0).size()];
//^Causes a "cannot find symbol" error
```

results in a "cannot find symbol" error. I'm sure there is a way to do this, I'm just unsure of the correct syntax? I suspect I need to iterate through the list and call size() somehow? Thanks for the help and let me know if I need to provide any other information.

Comment: I should probably also point out that `Point` is a custom class in this case and does not use the standard Java `Point` library.

Comment: The elements of your `mergePolyList` are *arrays* not collections.  Arrays do not have a `size()` method; instead, they have `length`.

Comment: Something simple, of course.`Poly.Point [] pArrayBox1 = new Poly.Point[mergePolyList.get(0).length];` works perfectly. Thank you John Bollinger, forgive the simple error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mergePolyList` is a list of arrays. You need to use the `length` attribute of arrays:

```
Poly.Point [] pArrayBox1 = new Poly.Point[mergePolyList.get(0).length];
```